# How to convert a multi-page PDF to images using ImageMagick for PHP?

Tags: cakephp, imagemagick

I want to convert the pdf file into images. I am using ImageMagick for image conversion in cakePHP.

When I take a PDF with a single page, its gets converted into image but the problem is when I take a PDF with multiple pages, then only the last page of the document is getting converted to image, instead of all pages.

How can I fix this?

This is the code I have.

```
 public function convertToImage() {  
     $this->layout = "ajax";

        $uploadfile=APP.WEBROOT_DIR.DS.'files'.DS.$this->request->data['f'];
        $uploaddir=APP.WEBROOT_DIR.DS.'files'.DS.'images'.DS;
        $im = new imagick();
        $im->setResolution(80,80);
        $im->readimage($uploadfile);//."[0]");
        $im->setImageFormat('jpeg');
        $image_name = $this->request->data['f'].".jpg";
        $imageprops = $im->getImageGeometry();
        if ($imageprops['width'] <= 1275 && $imageprops['height'] <= 1650) {
            // don't upscale
         } else {
             $im->resizeImage(1275,1650, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 0.9, true);
         }


        $im->writeImage($uploaddir .$image_name);
        $im->clear();
        $im->destroy();exit;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access each page by

```
$im->readimage($uploadfile."[".$pageNumber."]");
```

With imagemagick you can also read how many pages there are in a pdf:

```
$document = new Imagick('document.pdf'); 
$document->getNumberImages();
```

With this number you can iterate over each page and save an image.

As stated here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.imagick.php#111197 the pointer of imagemagick is set to the last page when used with pdfs.

Comment: I am wondering if it is possible to convert all pdf pages into one continuous image.

Comment: @amir-hajiha https://www.php.net/manual/en/imagick.appendimages.php#94568